# Rhyming is the key

Tags: word

> **To people I'm cold**
>   *I'm a huge fan of magic*
>   *I'm a huge fan of exotic pets*
>   **But I need to catch up on sleep**

Key:

**`Hint for the word I'm looking for.`**

*`Hint for two DIFFERENT words that rhyme with the word I'm looking for`*

Comment: @Rubio Wow, I totally forgot I didn't accept an answer yet. >.< Sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution:

I think it is

> Blizzard

Explanation:

**To people I'm cold**

> Blizzards are cold

*I'm a huge fan of magic*

> Rhymes with wizard

*I'm a huge fan of exotic pets*

> Lizards are exotic pets

**But I need to catch up on sleep**

> The middle letters of the word are 'zz', which is associated to sleeping

Comment: A guess for the last clue: the middle letters of your word mean sleep.

Comment: @archaephyrryx You were almost right with the last clue: Lizard and Wizard are both missing an additional "z" for Blizzard, therefore you need to "catch some z's", specifically an additional one.